# DateTime::createFromFormat() fails on simple example

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

The output of this is 'invalid date format'. What am I doing wrong?

```
$startTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("YYYY-mm-dd","2014-07-25");
if (FALSE===$startTimestamp) {
  die('invalid date format');
}
```

Comment: See [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for format codes

Comment: Docs say H for 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros and i for Minutes with leading zeros, but  I still get parse error with this `DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i", "2014-07-25 23:59", DateTimeZone::UTC)`  There appear to be 3 or 4 different date/time formats on the php.net manual site. Extremely confusing.

Comment: A parse error is likely to be a syntax error rather than an invalid date format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong date identifiers. Just one `Y`, `m`, and `d` are needed:

```
$startTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d","2014-07-25");
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it. What's wrong with my hours and minutes? $startTimestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:m", "2014-07-25 23:59", DateTimeZone::UTC);  I've tried HH:mm, too.

Comment: `H:i`. `i` is for minutes. `m` is for months.